# Объединить два датафрейма по совпадающим столбцам

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть два датафрейма: a1 и a2 в обоих есть столбцы id и месяц, но второй значительно больше первого нужно присоденить значения a2 к a1 в тех случаях когда a1['id']==a2['id'] и a1['месяц']==a2['месяц'] (оба эти условия должны выполняться одновременно. Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: приведите в вопросе небольшие примеры данных для входных и выходного датасетов. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае это делается при помощи метода [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
res = a1.merge(a2, on=["id", "месяц"])
```

**NOTE:** если в вопросе будут приведены примеры входных и выходных данных, то и в ответе будет конкретный пример.

PS по умолчанию `DataFrame.merge()` делает `INNER JOIN` - это как раз то, что вам нужно судя по описанию...